# How to connect Solr 4.4.0 to java application i have created and search data?

Tags: solr

I am new user to solr,I want to access and search the MYSQL database tables in java applications via solr.i am able to index my table in solr admin interface. Can anyone tell me how to connect and access MYSQL tables in java application so that i can search data fastly ? I was not able to understand tutorials whatever i found.

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to set up an instance of a Solr Server, SOlr will store and indexes from your database using the DataImportHandler.

http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/configuring-solr-4-data-import-handler.html

Solr creates indexes using Lucene, so you have two options, you can use classes from the Lucene jar file  or SolrJ to search your indexes.

OR

You can query Solr by sending http requests.  I set-up a Java Web Service so you can snatch some of my code if you need to.

http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/restful-java-web-service-for-solr.html

Answer (score 0):

Solr provides client libraries in java, ruby and other languagues to help you connect to Solr and query it.
Check for the Java library [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) to connect and query Solr.
If you are using Frameworks with your projects you might want to check for [Spring data](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-solr) as well which will help you seamlessly query and transform Solr response.